# Append an echo to file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix-shell

In linux, how do I do something like

```
echo 'hello world' > log.txt
```

but instead of overwriting the contents of log.txt, it appends to the end of of log.txt?

Comment: For full details see the all about [I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html).

Comment: @Zoredache: Great reference! +1

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
echo 'hello world' >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
>>
```

In place of:

```
>
```

Answer (score 5):

In Linux you can also use the useful HERE TAG for multiline append :

```
cat >> log.txt << EOF
hello word 1
hello word 2
hello word 3
EOF
```

Linux shell's are more more powerful than windows command prompt! ;)

Comment: While shell may be more powerful than cmd.exe, I would argue it's not more powerful than powershell.

Comment: PowerShell is a Scripting language and for this need to be compared with another scripting language for example Perl then Perl is more more powerful than PowerShell . ;) :D

Comment: Naughty! No language jihads here!

Answer (score 4):

echo 'hello world' >> log.txt